# How to use the google-api-client to retrieve google calendar events with Android

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I have figured out the gdata libraries are not compatible with Android and have switched to the google-api-client libraries. I have followed the v2-atom-android sample but it does not cover how to retrieve events, only calendars. For my app, I need to be able to download the calendars and events - does anyone know how to do this with google-api-client libraries?

Comment: Do you find solution for this matter? I stuck on this for days already. Please sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a GET request to a given event feed link which is included as a property of each calendar received as part of request to a Calendar feed. 
I mean either `link rel='self'` if ATOM or `selfLink` if JSONC.

For more information, please refer to this address:

[Retrieving events](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#RetrievingEvents)

Regards,
PrieJos

Comment: Can you post an example of some code for which you describe above?  From looking at the CalendarAndroidSample.java and related files for the Google "v2-atom-android-sample" I get a vague idea of what your trying to say, but seeing some code would help me understand better.